# View containing @Binding updates needlessly, causing performance issues

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following root view

```swift
@StateObject private var vm = NCMediaViewModel()
@State private var title = "Media"

///...

 var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            MediaScrollView(columnCountStages: $columnCountStages, columnCountStagesIndex: $columnCountStagesIndex, title: $title)
                .environmentObject(vm)
                .environmentObject(parent)
                .onPreferenceChange(TitlePreferenceKey.self) { value in
                    title = value
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                    let isScrolledToTop = value.y >= -10

                    withAnimation(.default) {
                        titleColor = isScrolledToTop ? Color.primary : .white
                        toolbarItemsColor = isScrolledToTop ? .blue : .white
                        toolbarColors = isScrolledToTop ? [.clear] : [.black.opacity(0.8), .black.opacity(0.0)]
                    }
                }

            HStack(content: {
                HStack {
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                        .foregroundStyle(titleColor)

                    Spacer()

                    Button(action: {
                        title = String(Int.random(in: 1...50))
                        //                        vm.isInSelectMode.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text(NSLocalizedString(vm.isInSelectMode ? "_cancel_" : "_select_", comment: "")).font(.system(size: 14))
                            .foregroundStyle(toolbarItemsColor)
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                    .padding(.vertical, 3)
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .cornerRadius(.infinity)
                    .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                        let isScrolledToTop = value.y >= -10

                        withAnimation(.default) {
                            titleColor = isScrolledToTop ? Color.primary : .white
                            toolbarItemsColor = isScrolledToTop ? .blue : .white
                            toolbarColors = isScrolledToTop ? [.clear] : [.black.opacity(0.8), .black.opacity(0.0)]
                        }
                    }

                    if vm.isInSelectMode, !vm.selectedMetadatas.isEmpty {
                        ToolbarCircularButton(imageSystemName: "trash.fill", color: .red)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                showDeleteConfirmation = true
                            }
                            .confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $showDeleteConfirmation) {
                                Button(NSLocalizedString("_delete_selected_media_", comment: ""), role: .destructive) {
                                    vm.deleteSelectedMetadata()
                                }
                            }
                    }

                    Menu {
                        if vm.isInSelectMode, !vm.selectedMetadatas.isEmpty {
                            Section {
                                Button {
                                    vm.copyOrMoveSelectedMetadataInApp()
                                } label: {
                                    Label(NSLocalizedString("_move_selected_files_", comment: ""), systemImage: "arrow.up.right.square")
                                }

                                Button {
                                    vm.copySelectedMetadata()
                                } label: {
                                    Label(NSLocalizedString("_copy_file_", comment: ""), systemImage: "doc.on.doc")
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Section {
                                Picker(NSLocalizedString("_media_view_options_", comment: ""), selection: $vm.filter) {
                                    Label(NSLocalizedString("_media_viewimage_show_", comment: ""), systemImage: "photo.fill").tag(Filter.onlyPhotos)

                                    Label(NSLocalizedString("_media_viewvideo_show_", comment: ""), systemImage: "video.fill").tag(Filter.onlyVideos)

                                    Text(NSLocalizedString("_media_show_all_", comment: "")).tag(Filter.all)
                                }.pickerStyle(.menu)

                                Button {
                                    selectMediaFolder()
                                } label: {
                                    Label(NSLocalizedString("_select_media_folder_", comment: ""), systemImage: "folder")
                                }
                            }

                            Section {
                                Button(action: {
                                    if let tabBarController = vm.appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                                        NCDocumentPickerViewController(tabBarController: tabBarController, isViewerMedia: true, allowsMultipleSelection: false, viewController: parent)
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    Label(NSLocalizedString("_play_from_files_", comment: ""), systemImage: "play.circle")
                                })

                                Button(action: {
                                    showPlayFromURLAlert = true
                                }, label: {
                                    Label(NSLocalizedString("_play_from_url_", comment: ""), systemImage: "link")
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        ToolbarCircularButton(imageSystemName: "ellipsis", color: $toolbarItemsColor)
                    }
                }
            })
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding([.horizontal, .top], 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: toolbarColors), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))

        }
        .onRotate { orientation in
            if orientation.isLandscapeHardCheck {
                columnCountStages = [4, 6, 8]
            } else {
                columnCountStages = [4, 4, 4]
            }
        }
        .onAppear { vm.loadMediaFromDB() }
        .onChange(of: vm.isInSelectMode) { newValue in
            if newValue == false { vm.selectedMetadatas.removeAll() }
        }
        .onChange(of: columnCountStagesIndex) { _ in
            columnCountChanged = true
        }
        .alert("", isPresented: $showPlayFromURLAlert) {
            TextField("https://...", text: $playFromUrlString)
                .keyboardType(.URL)
                .textContentType(.URL)

            Button(NSLocalizedString("_cancel_", comment: ""), role: .cancel) {}
            Button(NSLocalizedString("_ok_", comment: "")) {
                playVideoFromUrl()
            }
        } message: {
            Text(NSLocalizedString("_valid_video_url_", comment: ""))
        }
        .gesture(
            MagnificationGesture(minimumScaleDelta: 0)
                .onChanged { scale in
                    print(scale)
                    if !columnCountChanged {
                        let newZoom = Double(columnCountStages[columnCountStagesIndex]) * 1 / scale
                        let newZoomIndex = findClosestZoomIndex(value: newZoom)
                        columnCountStagesIndex = newZoomIndex
                    }
                }
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    columnCountChanged = false
                })
        )
    }
```

I'm initializing `MediaScrollView` and passing certain `@State`s as `@Binding`s, one of them being `title`.

```swift
struct MediaScrollView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: NCMediaViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var parent: NCMediaUIKitWrapper

    @Binding var columnCountStages: [Int]
    @Binding var columnCountStagesIndex: Int
    @Binding var title: String

    var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                    ForEach(vm.metadatas.chunked(into: columnCountStages[columnCountStagesIndex]), id: \.self) { rowMetadatas in
                        NCMediaRow(metadatas: rowMetadatas, cache: vm.cache, isInSelectMode: $vm.isInSelectMode) { tappedThumbnail, isSelected in

                            //TODO: Put in VM
                            if vm.isInSelectMode, isSelected {
                                vm.selectedMetadatas.append(tappedThumbnail.metadata)
                            } else {
                                vm.selectedMetadatas.removeAll(where: { $0.ocId == tappedThumbnail.metadata.ocId })
                            }

                            if !vm.isInSelectMode {
                                let selectedMetadata = tappedThumbnail.metadata
                                vm.onCellTapped(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                                NCViewer.shared.view(viewController: parent, metadata: selectedMetadata, metadatas: vm.metadatas, imageIcon: tappedThumbnail.image)
                            }
                        } onCellContextMenuItemSelected: { thumbnail, selection in
                            let selectedMetadata = thumbnail.metadata

                            switch selection {
                            case .addToFavorites:
                                vm.addToFavorites(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                            case .details:
                                NCActionCenter.shared.openShare(viewController: parent, metadata: selectedMetadata, page: .activity)
                            case .openIn:
                                vm.openIn(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                            case .saveToPhotos:
                                vm.saveToPhotos(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                            case .viewInFolder:
                                vm.viewInFolder(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                            case .modify:
                                vm.modify(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                            case .delete:
                                vm.delete(metadatas: selectedMetadata)
                            }
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            title = CCUtility.getTitleSectionDate(rowMetadatas.first?.date as? Date) ?? ""
                        }

                        if vm.needsLoadingMoreItems {
                            ProgressView()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .onAppear { vm.loadMoreItems() }
                                .padding(.top, 10)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 70)
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin)
                })
            }
            .preference(key: TitlePreferenceKey.self, value: title)
            .refreshable {
                await vm.onPullToRefresh()
            }
            // Not possible to move the refresh control view via SwiftUI, so we have to introspect the internal UIKit views to move it.
            // TODO: Maybe .contespontMargins() will resolve this but it's iOS 17+
            .introspect(.scrollView, on: .iOS(.v15...)) { scrollView in
                scrollView.refreshControl?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                scrollView.refreshControl?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.superview!.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true
                scrollView.refreshControl?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
    }
}
```

`onAppear` updates the `title` binding during scrolling, and in turn that updates the root view. The problem is that also updates the child view and also every `NCMediaRow` and during scrolling that affects the performance. There is noticeable stutter when the `title` updates during scrolling.

```
struct NCMediaRow: View {
    let metadatas: [tableMetadata]
    let cache: UIImageLRUCache
    @Binding var isInSelectMode: Bool
    let onCellSelected: (ScaledThumbnail, Bool) -> Void
    let onCellContextMenuItemSelected: (ScaledThumbnail, ContextMenuSelection) -> Void
    @StateObject private var vm = NCMediaRowViewModel()
    private let spacing: CGFloat = 2

    @State var size: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()

        HStack(spacing: spacing) {
            if vm.rowData.scaledThumbnails.isEmpty {
                ForEach(metadatas, id: \.self) { metadata in
                    NCMediaLoadingCell(itemsInRow: metadatas.count, metadata: metadata, rowSize: size.width, spacing: spacing)
                }
            } else {
                ForEach(vm.rowData.scaledThumbnails, id: \.self) { thumbnail in
                    NCMediaCell(thumbnail: thumbnail, shrinkRatio: vm.rowData.shrinkRatio, isInSelectMode: $isInSelectMode, onSelected: onCellSelected, onContextMenuItemSelected: onCellContextMenuItemSelected, isFavorite: thumbnail.metadata.favorite)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear
                    .onAppear {
                        size = proxy.size
                    }
            }
        )
        .onAppear {
            vm.configure(metadatas: metadatas, cache: cache)
            vm.downloadThumbnails(rowWidth: size.width, spacing: spacing)
        }
    }
}
```

I added `Self._printChanges()` to the `NCMediaRow` view, and this is what is printed out:

```
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
NCMediaRow: @self, _isInSelectMode changed.
```

As you can see, all the rows on the screen are updated when the `title` updates.

---

Removing the `title` @Binding and updating it only in the root view will stop updating the `NCMediaRow`s.

I'm not sure how I can stop the `NCMediaRow`s from updating even with this @Binding. I need it to be able to update the `title`.

I tried to:

- Remove the `ZStack` from the root view as I read it sometimes updates all the views it contains.
- Removing `isInSelectMode` since it appears in the print, but `@self` still changes.
- Removing the @Binding and instead using a `PreferenceKey` to update the `title`. I assumed since it's a child to parent association it will not update the child, but I guess it's still a `@Binding` in a way and the `NCMediaRow`s still update.

Comment: This needs a [mre]

Comment: This is the main disadvantage of ObservableObject and using “self”. You should watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

Comment: @loremipsum Only the VMs are an ObservableObject, I don't think they are affecting this.

Comment: They are… they invalidate the entire view instead of taking advantage of precise updates. This is the main argument against ViewModels in SwiftUI

Comment: @loremipsum I see, I will look into the video you mentioned.

Comment: @loremipsum But, if the VM is really the problem, wouldn't it say `NCMediaRow: @self, _vm changed.` instead?

Comment: Make a simple sample project, reproduce with you setup and then get rid of the `ObservableObject` test it out, we don't have enough to be any real help.

Comment: You can improve performance by breaking it up into small View structs. Remove the View model `ObservableObject` since you are using async/await there is no need for that. Also the `ForEach` `id: \.self` is a major bug, you must specify real id.